# Drools 6.5.0 DRL compile time increased 10 times

Tags: java, jboss, compilation, drools

We were using package builder from drools 5.3 earlier.
Now after the upgrade to 6.5.0.. We are using kie api.
The compilation time of the drl has increased to 10 times.
For eg. The below code.

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
    kfs.write(resource);

    KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs);
```

// the below line now takes 150 seconds for 428 rules. Earlier it was taking 10 seconds.

```
    kb.buildAll();

    results = kb.getResults();
```

Earlier drools version 5.3, jdk 1.7

New version 6.5.0, jdk 1.8

Few questions around this:

1. Does the kie api takes longer time in compiling rules?
2. Is there anything which can be done to improve the performance, increasing RAM for eg.
3. We are calling java classes/methods in our DRLs, could that be a problem?
4. PackageBuilder Api in drools 5.3 was compiling much faster, the same DRLs, do we need to modify our DRL for better performance.. Any links?

Comment: This is s a statement, not a question. If you want to discuss execution times, the Drools user list is a better place.

Comment: Hi Laune, i have updated my questions with proper queries. Could you please give some pointers?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923356/drools-rules-compilation-performance

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue.  I updated my drools version from 6.2.0.Final to 6.5.0.Final (both using java 1.8) and experienced a 10x increase in the time taken in creating a new KieSession.  We have ~1800 rules which includes 83 Decision Tables.

In version 6.2.0.Final newKieSession took approx 2 minutes.
In version 6.5.0.Final and 7.0.0.Final, newKieSession takes 20 minutes and I think our rule processing also hangs/stalls.

Can you try using 6.2.0.Final, 6.3.0.Final or 6.4.0.Final (although in version 6.4.0.Final version only, I receive a NullPointerException during rule firing).

I setup my kieSession and have my kieBase setup using the following

```
KieContainer kieContainer = KieServices.Factory.get().newKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("my-rules");
```

This reads the kmodule.xml file in my classpath which contains

```
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <kbase name="rules" packages="*">
        <ksession name="my-rules"/>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

Answer (score 1):

The compile time performance degradation you reported has been very likely caused by the issue reported here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1581 that has been already fixed on master. As a side note and regardless of this issue I strongly suggest to avoid using evals in your rules: they're useless in 99.9% of cases, worsen readability of rules and may also negatively impact runtime performances.